# How to implement 2FA without user phone

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, account-security

I have a problem: users share their credentials with other users.
I have to create a way to ensure that users are using their own credentials to access the system. I think creating a 2 factor authentication, but I can not use the user's phone. Does anyone know a way to do this through software and not hardware (like biometric device)?

There is a detail that discards solutions about educating users. Some users have reported that their credentials have been stolen and used by former officials, and unfortunately we had a real case with this situation.

Comment: 2FA is not helping against account sharing. Sure it could... but the most convenient implementation (i. e. rotating code on user smartphone) certainly will not prevent it. Educate your users instead.

Comment: require something they won't want to share, like an SSN. hash it on the server.

Comment: You don't solve account sharing by adding more barriers. You solve account sharing by having people not share accounts. That is to say, make people aware they should not, make people responsible for their actions, and allow people to do their job efficiently.

Comment: Is this software used inside some company where you can forbid users to share accounts and send them to training? Or is this accessable by the public (i. e. a webapp) where noone cares what the TOS says?

Comment: @dandavis SSN is an identifier (unique name)  not an authenticator (password)

Comment: maybe post a bounty for username-password pairs to be paid by the account-holder

Comment: @Jasen he never said to use SSN as a password. And the bounty idea is colossally bad. You will have users (if local to each other) hacking each other to get credentials to "sell", not only for the bounty but to each other.

Comment: @BlueWizard
I need it to fix the past and help in the future, educating users takes years, I need something immediate (to yesterday)

Comment: So if the credentials are stolen then offer a password reset box so the original user can reobtain access and change the password?

Comment: If the passwords are already out there then the account admin should schedule password resets for every affected account (if unknown: every account). The standard procedure here is enforcing regulary password changes, although success of this method is limited (people usually will just increment some number inside their password which makes this process useless).

Comment: Your edited your question stating that credentials leaked outside the company. What exactly hinders you (or the account admin) to roll out a password reset for the affected accounts?

Comment: Why can't you use the users phone? Has your company no business phones? How important is this topic for your company (read as "what's your budget?").

Comment: Why not use a code sent to email? That's a pretty standard approach.

Comment: @BlueWizard 
Budgeting is not a problem, but the processes for device purchases are. My question is time, I need to do something quick and effective while processes occur.
The password reset process already exists, but until the user notices the theft is too late.
They do not own corporate cell phone and using personal cell phone is out of the question.

Comment: @schroeder does not work, because it use the same password as login.

Comment: Ok, hold on, that's a VERY relevant detail! Your question says "system"! That could mean customers accessing your service or a local authentication of a company resource or even a 3rd party service for your company. You are talking about your corporate authentication system which includes email! If you had been more explicit at the start, you would have received much higher quality answers. PLEASE edit your question to provide more context! For instance, who are the "officials" you mention?

Comment: @carlos also, why not their personal email?

Comment: Roll out global password reset and then give every employee an employee id card that can be used to unlock accounts and stuff.

Comment: Getting relevant data out of you, @carlos, is a very painfull process. Resetting account passwords and rolling out employee IDs is standard procedure and not in line with this question and/or this SE site. Please rethink what your question really is about, maybe ask your supervisor or use an alternative stack exchange site. Maybe one of these can answer your workplace related question better: workplace.stackexchange.com or superuser.com/

Comment: Seems like there are some players out there like ShoBadge and OneLogin that may have answers.

Comment: @carlos what is the nature of the system ? is it a web / desktop app or an authentication provider ? is the user email safe from this behavior ? I mean sharing credentials

Answer (score 8, accepted):

2-factor logins consist of 2 of three things: something you either have, are, or know.  Passwords are something known, so you'd have to implement something you are or have.  Biometrics, ie  "measuring people"; iris scanners, fingerprint scanners, voiceprints, hand scanners, and facial recognition are examples of biometrics that either require specialized equipment, or [can easily be fooled by someone with access to a dollar store](https://www.theverge.com/2016/5/2/11540962/iphone-samsung-fingerprint-duplicate-hack-security). So unless you have a human supervising them, biometrics are out.

So that leaves something you have.

A simple and annoying way to do this is to restrict user logins to their computer.  Sure, you know Bob's password, but you don't have his computer.  So login fails.  That's about the cheapest way t o do it.  Otherwise you can issue hardware tokens.  Then you'd enter your password and the code from the hardware token or have the hardware token inserted into the USB port.

The challenge to doing this via software is having it be something you have or are.  Software by definition is generally neither of them.

PS you already know this, but you have a huge problem with people sharing passwords.  Effectively you have no audit trail or way to specifically hold someone accountable for what was done under their login.  I assume you already knew that...

Comment: Thank you. But, my scenery is very complicated, because restrict user by computer is not possible, the users don't have fixed place, like a "call center". 
"Biometrics are out, so that leave s something you have.", why? You have biometrics, such as having token hardware or a cell phone.

Comment: Anyway, I need a solution by software, I don't have enough time to buy more than 100k of devices be it biometrics, token hardware or cell phones.

Comment: @carlos. biometrics is  "measuring people" , iris scanners, fingerprint scanners, voiceprints, hand scanners, and facial recognition are examples of biometrics.  something in your pocket is a security token, not biometrics.

Comment: You can by definition of 2FA not have it implemented purely in software. (unless in software is a software on another device like a phone or hardware token, obviously)

Answer (score 3):

<sub>I'm turning my previous comments into a proper answer</sub>

The solution to stopping account sharing within your company is to

### Educate the user & Make registration convenient

No gimmick in the world will prevent your users from account sharing if they are not informed about it. 
No matter how strong the 2FA is coupled to the person. Requiring a DNA sample upon login just prompts people to keep a jar of spit besides their desk.

Educate their users and tell them why loss of audit trail is bad for them (and their coworkers).

If your registration is cumbersome then make it easier. For example instead of them sending you (the admin) an email maybe make a simple web form where they can register with their employee ID.
Lowering entry bounds is always good when it comes to stopping account sharing.

---

<sub>*This answer has become obsolete after the question was edited*</sub>

Comment: I believe you did not understand my problem.